# looking for books on topological semigroup:

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, semigroups, book-recommendation

I'm looking for several books on topological semigroup:

> 1. Topological semigroups: history, theory, applications. Karl Heinrich Hofmann
>      Mathematics Research Library, Tulane University.
> 2. The theory of topological semigroups. James Harvey Carruth, ‎John A. Hildebrant, ‎R. J. Koch - 1983

If you have other books related topological semigroup, could you provide me a copy?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: @Paul I know how to obtain freely some books on topological semigroups (in particular, [2]), but the policy of MSE forbids me to tell this here.